# Typo3 - Filter search frontend

Tags: php, typo3

I created a TYPO3 extension with a List and Detail View and now I want to add a searchbar above the list view to filter the List.

I want a User to have a Field, he can type some Keyword and I want to search it at my "firstname" and "lastname" Database-Column of my Extension. If Keyword is found, show only the User.

I tried to write some code but I couldn't get my filter to work, when I click on "search", nothing is happening.

At the moment my Controller and Repo looks like this:

Controller :

```
    public function listAction()
    {
        $users = $this->frontendUser->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('users', $users);

        if ($this->request->hasArgument('name')) {
            $name = $this->request->getArgument('name');
            $users = $this->frontendUser->findName($name);
            $this->view->assign('users', $users);
        }
        
    }
```

repository :

```
class FrontendUserRepository extends Repository
{
    public function findName($querystring = '') {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        if ($querystring) {
            $constraints = [
                $query->like('firstname', '%'.$querystring.'%'),
                $query->like('lastname', '%'.$querystring.'%')
            ];
            $query->matching(
                $query->logicalOr($constraints)
            );
        }
        return $query->execute();
    }
}
```

List.html :

```
<form action="#">
   <label for="name">By name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>

        <f:for each="{users}" as="user">
            <p>{user.firstname} {user.lastname}</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tel">{user.telephone}</li>
                <li class="service">{user.name}</li>
                <li class="loc">{user.address}</li>
            </ul>
        </f:for>
```

Someone can tell me where i'm wrong ? thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found issues:

1. Controller

Remove `$` in assigned variable.

Change

```
$this->view->assign('$results', $results);
```

to

```
$this->view->assign('results', $results);
```

2. Repository

Add missing logicalOr() method.

Change

```
$query->matching(
    $query->like('firstname', '%'.$querystring.'%'),
    $query->like('lastname', '%'.$querystring.'%')
);
```

to

```
$constraints = [
    $query->like('firstname', '%'.$querystring.'%'),
    $query->like('lastname', '%'.$querystring.'%')
];
$query->matching(
    $query->logicalOr($constraints)
);
```

3. View

This can not work, it's no official Fluid syntax:

```
<f:else if="{results}">
```

Use

```
<f:if condition="{results}">
   <f:then>
       Output results code
   </f:then>
   <f:else>
       <f:if condition="{users}">
           Output users code
       </f:if>
   </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Suggestion:

Use only one variable `users` for your results. Afaics the output in HTML is the same, so why not using the same variable. Then there is no need to do a complex if -> else -> if structure

Comment: Sorry, Thomas, but `<f:else if="{results}">` *is* FLUID syntax - since TYPO3 8.0. Details in Thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/29461713/6783328 or in the official docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-extbasefluid/8.7/en-us/Fluid/ViewHelper/If.html#complex-conditional-statements

Comment: Never have seen and used that...thanks for the link

Comment: I updated my post with the corrections, using only the users variable and removing if conditions, but the problem persists, I don't know if it's because of the <form action="#"> ? I want to redirect the user to the same page after using the filter

Comment: Ehm, yes. For `action="#"` "User agent behavior for a value other than an HTTP URI is undefined." applies (https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html). If you want the input to be processed by the webserver (or TYPO3 on it), you should send the data. `<f:form ...>` should be your choice: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Form.html